# Selenium Webdriver to wait for loading frame content in c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, frame

I am doing Selenium WebDriver automation where I am facing a very critical issue for frame. In my Application there is link named
--Print. When user clicks on Print link ...one frame window gets opened . On that frame there is submit button along with checkboxes and links. When user selects some checkboxes and clicks on "Submit" button that time again the result means" Selected checkboxes and their links" got displayed on that frame.

But problem is like there are many links which is loaded after some time. We have requirement like do not use explicit wait because we are doing performance testing.  So i have to wail till all frame content load without explicit wait.

I have tried many things like below

```
while (!table.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(),'" + tin +
    "')]/following::span")).Text.Equals("Complete"))
                        //while(!table.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(),'" + tin +
    "')]/following::span")).Text.Equals("Complete"))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        TWOBase.Logger.LogInfo("Printed return " + tin + " is displayed in Print Returns Results Grid with Status
Complete");
```

In short i have to verify --when number is TIN there should be status completed...But its taking time

Note: I am able switch to frame and i can verify TIN number and status also but i have to avoid wait ... i have to read grid once frame is completely loaded and ready.

Here is my complete method:
 2.

```
public void TestMethod(List<string> ssn)
        {
            try
            {               
               TWOBase.Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);

                TWOBase.Logger.LogInfo("Print Returns Results Dialog Box Is Opened");
                IWebElement table = TWOBase.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ResultsGrid"));
                                TWOBase.Logger.LogInfo("Verifying Print returns are displayed in Print Returns Results...");


                foreach (string tin in ssn)
                {
                    while (!table.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(),'" + tin +
"')]/following::span")).Text.Equals("Complete"))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    TWOBase.Logger.LogInfo("Printed return " + tin + " is displayed in Print Returns Results Grid with Status Complete");

                }
                TWOBase.Stop();

                if (!ReturnDisplayed)
                    TWOBase.TestCaseResult = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TWOBase.Logger.LogException(ex);

            }

        }
```

Comment: Are you talking about frame or window?

Comment: Its Frame...not window  please have a look at attached snapshot

Comment: No snapshot and please format your code. Cannot read it

Comment: In Short i want Selenium Wendriver to wait till whole/complete Frame load without explicit wait

Comment: When you say complete frame do you mean the elements inside that? Because it can make difference

Comment: Yes i have to wait till loading of all element inside that ....If u have seen attached snapshot then u might get idea....like while loading frame ..there is grid inside frame....which has columns ...so two columns text is getting updated "Status" and "Download Links"...hence when i retrieve grid without wait and checks for TIN and Status inside it. So that time it is giving "StaleNullReferenceException"/Element no longer exits. But when i add explicit wait before reading grid and checked inside values then it runs fine

Comment: If you do not know how many elements are going to be there then wait for the one you are looking for. Is that the case?

Comment: I know there will be always 20 values on grid inside frame but those are always new. I can verify all values but i need to add explicit wait...can't we check to wait until whole frame content load in selenium webdriver load and then perform operation on grid... i have already checked to wait until last element in that grid is not displayed but not working

Comment: can we wait till all loading of frame content in selenium webdriver or Coded Ui??